# Issues connecting to LAN when using multiple network interfaces

Tags: networking, ssh, troubleshooting

So I am sure this question has been asked before because I've spent about a week working through every solution I can find, however none of them are working for me and at this point I have no clue why. Basically I have a wired and wireless network interface the wired is connected to a LAN which is connected to the WAN and the other is a stand alone LAN. So far the most transparent solution I have found is this https://www.thomas-krenn.com/en/wiki/Two_Default_Gateways_on_One_System. Which leaves me with a routing table

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 enp10s0
0.0.0.0         10.0.0.1        0.0.0.0         UG    600    0        0 wlp3s0
10.0.0.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     600    0        0 wlp3s0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 enp10s0
```

my interfaces file

```
# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto wlp3s0
allow-hotplug wlp3s0
iface wlp3s0 inet static
    address 10.0.0.2
    netmask 255.255.255.0

auto enp10s0
allow-hotplug enp10s0
iface  enp10s0 inet dhcp

#Routing
post-up ip route add 10.0.0.0/24 dev wlp3s0 src 10.0.0.2 table rt2
post-up ip route add default via 10.0.0.1 dev wlp3s0 table rt2
post-up ip rule add from 10.0.0.2/32 table rt2
post-up ip rule add to 10.0.0.2/32 table rt2
```

the output of `ip route list table rt2` followed by `ip rule show` is

```
0:  from all lookup local 
32764:  from all to 10.0.0.2 lookup rt2 
32765:  from 10.0.0.2 lookup rt2 
32766:  from all lookup main
```

The desired outcome for the system would be as follows

[image: Desired Network Layout]

I've started to follow a lot of the suggestions in the comments and apparently although I was defining my static IP in interfaces the router function I was using to reserve the IP still used DHCP so I turned of the DHCP server and am now not able to connect my best guess is I have not given enough information about my static IP in interfaces but I'm not to sure, thats what I'm playing around with right now, I also commented out the routing section since the general consensus is that I don't need it. In response to some of the comments I'm running Debian stretch and there are no error messages on ping or ssh they just time out.

Comment: I feel like you should ask a question. Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.

Comment: Sorry I'm missing something and I'm not sure what, so I was trying to post my process to see if a more experienced user could catch a rookie mistake in my work.

Comment: You appear to be making this more complicated than it is. If I’m understanding right, 192.168.1.x is your LAN with internet access. 10.0.0.x is your isolated network. You want to ping a system in the 10.0.0.x range and it’s failing. I see nothing to indicate why you are adding a second default gateway of 10.0.0.1. Are you trying to reach other systems beyond 10.0.0.1? There shouldn’t be two gateways. Only 1 on 192.168.1.1. Your system already knows 10.0.0.x is directly connected. There shouldn’t be routing rules or tables or anything changed for this default behavior.

Comment: default gateway 10.0.0.1 was added automatically, I can try manually removing the entry from the table though.

Comment: Is the network adapter configured via DHCP? If it was static, then you remove the gateway setting in your interfaces cfg. If it's via DHCP you'll need to make sure you block the default gateway in your configuration somewhere. There shouldn't be any changing of routing tables or anything, this is all basic behavior.

Comment: What should I statically set the gateway as for my 10.0.0.2 address then? I am updating the question to include my interfaces file

Comment: Nothing. It doesn't need a gateway to communicate on the 10.0.0.x network.

Comment: Why are you explicitly adding a default route via 10.0.0.1? Is 10.0.0.1 a gateway? As I read your question, you only have one gateway. So all the weird routing stuff you're doing makes no sense and you should just get rid of it. You just have two interfaces to two networks and nothing special at all.

Comment: OK, I started writing this comment before all those other comments appeared, but anyway … It would help if you could give us a lot more information. For starters, what’s the device you’re talking about?  Oh, sure, it’s obviously a PC — except you don’t say, and assumptions like that are not always right.  And what operating system is it running? Then, tell us all your IP addresses. Yes, I see that there are a few of them sprinkled throughout your question, and I guess that 192.168.1.1 is your Internet router, but I’m not clear on what 10.0.0.1 and 10.0.0.2 are. A diagram might help. … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  You say, “I … assume … targeting 10.0.0.2 I would be able to connect to the remote computer or at least ping the gateway …”. What gateway do you have on the wireless LAN? Oh, and I agree that, unless you have millions of hosts on your “stand alone” wireless LAN, you shouldn’t have a default routing rule pointing to it. Finally, please show all error messages exactly.              Please do not respond in comments; edit your question to make it clearer and more complete.

Comment: Just to concur with everyone, you don't need any additional table here. That would be needed only if there were two routes to the same destination, but that's not your case. The "Problem Description" from your link is misleading, it doesn't explain the goal of having two default gateways at the same time. Compare with the real problem case solved, at this link (which, again,  is not your case): http://lartc.org/howto/lartc.rpdb.multiple-links.html . The explanation is clear: two default gateways to the same place(s): the Internet.

Comment: We're not trying to beat you up over this, but your network diagram is either drawn inaccurately, or you're missing the basic concepts of networking and routing. You may be confusing the function of a switch and a router. Home type routers, have a switch and a router built in. On the right side of your drawing you appear to show two sides to your router (which would normally be two distinct networks) yet you have the same network address on both sides (10.0.0.x). This is not possible and will not work. The left side looks accurate.

Comment: I'm unsure what you mean as both are assigned 10.0.0.x address 10.0.0.1 is the gateway address, If im on the local network wouldn't they be the same which is why I don't necessarily need a routing table?

Comment: Look at your left side of the drawing. See how you show both sides of the router. One side is your WAN and the other side is your LAN 192.168.1.x (they are two different networks). Now look at your right side, see how you show both sides of your router. On one side you show a network (10.0.0.x) and on the other side you show a network (10.0.0.x) - they are the same network. This is not possible. Now, if "Router 2" is actually just being used as a switch - then it makes sense. If this is a "home" router then that would mean you have nothing plugged in to the WAN port. Please clarify.

Comment: Yes I see now what you mean by the drawing being unclear router 2 is just a switch, they are on the same side with no wan. I was able to ping my gate way so I'm hoping I'll be able to transition to ssh to another ip on the same network. Thanks for all the constructive criticism I'm sure it will make my next post a lot more clear from the get go. IDK how this works but if one of you makes an answer I think I can accept it to close this?

Comment: Then it now makes sense. And in this case, you will not use any special routing rules or anything. You'll simply let enp10s0 continue to pull a DHCP address which will include an address and default gateway on 192.168.1.x, and you will statically assign 10.0.0.2 to wlp3s0 with no gateway specified. That's all there is to it. The device at 10.0.0.3 also doesn't have a "gateway." So, there is no sense in configuring one there either but it won't break what you are trying to do.

Comment: Yes I got everything up and running thanks for all your help and patience.